# Hibernate JPA generating tons of sequence.nextval queries for a oneToMany entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a parent table and a child table. Parent may contains many child entries.
Whenever I do a parent save, it generates many `select` statements for the sequence generation of each child entry.
`select ITEM_SEQ,nextval from dual`

Is there any way to avoid this. I am looking for a straight statement that will not produce this `nextval` generation there by improve the performance.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Bucket")
public class Bucket {
Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bucket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Item> items = new TreeSet<>();
.....
....
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ItemGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ItemGenerator", sequenceName = "ITEM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ITEM_SEQ")
    private Long id;
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GenerationType.SEQUENCE` needs additional call to get new ID from DB sequence. This is not performance problem in most applications. If you don't want it happen use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead.

Comment: The problem with `Identity` is that it wont support batch inserts. I am thinking to increase the allocation size to 50 both on entity and in the DB sequence